# What would be the doppler effect in the a 2.42GHz signal coming from a satellite in orbit around Mars, received on Earth ground station?

Tags: mars, solar-wind, conjunction, doppler-ranging, gps-radio-occultation

Say there is a satellite in orbit around Mars, and it sends a signal at such a time that it is more or less behind the Sun. In that case, Mars would be "Occulted" by the Sun.

That signal is then received on Earth at a ground station. (Place won't matter)

What would be the doppler effect introduced to the signal if the signal is of 2.4 GHz?

Here, there are a lot of things to consider, as not only the relative motion between the planets and satellite matters, but also the relativistic doppler due to Sun's mass would as well, if the signal is anywhere between 5 to 10 Solar radii from the Sun at its point of closest approach.

How do I calculate the "Theoretical Doppler" the signal will have in the above scenario?

This is a schematic of the geometry -

[image]

> Date: 24 July 2012 Satellite: Mars Express Depicts: Artist's
> impression of radio sounding of the solar corona with Mars Express
> Copyright: ESA/AOES Medialab

Comment: I feel that the major issues would be relative motion of the satellite and the planet Mars, relative motion of this system with respect to the Earth, relativistic doppler due to the Sun, and the doppler due to atmosphere of the two planets. However, I am not sure on what/ how to proceed, and am also unsure whether Mars would have an impact at all, considering its thin atmosphere.

Comment: 2.4 Ghz is one of the major WiFi frequency bands. Many people have trouble getting that to work from one end of their house to the other and you want to go a couple hundred million miles?

Comment: Yeah, but it is something space agencies use to send/receive data from their satellites around other bodies. However, since its weak, huge dishes, around 32m or so are used to get the signal.